# python list not getting appended

Tags: python, list, append

The list is not getting appended I want to append board list for both users using for loop how can I do this

```
from random import randint
user1 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}
user2 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}
users = [user1, user2]
def set_board(users):
    for x in range(5):
        users["board"].append(x)
def print_board(users):
    for row in users["board"]:
        print(" ".join(row))
print("Let's start")
print(print_board(user1))
print(print_board(user2))
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more specific.

Comment: provide info about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You never call `set_board`
2. `print_board` don't return anything, so you cannot print the return value
3. You are trying to set a dict key for every element in a list, this is not possible.

Here is a working version:

```
from random import randint
user1 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}
user2 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}
users = [user1, user2]    # Actually this is not used anymore

def set_board(user):
    for x in range(5):
        user["board"].append(x)

def print_board(user):
    print(' '.join(str(user["board"])))

print("Let's start")
set_board(user1)
set_board(user2)
print_board(user1)
print_board(user2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call the set_board() function. Also, the print(print_board(user1)) statement will not print anything since there is no return value in print_board() => just call print_board(user1)

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you never actually call 'set_board', but it would have failed if you did.  When you append the integers you're appending to users['board'], not to user1['board'] or user2['board'].  In fact python should have thrown a TypeError when you tried to make that assignment.

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Something like:

```
def set_board(users):
    for my_user in users:
        for x in range(5):
            my_user.append(x)
```

would append the integers to each of the users (user1 and user2).
T